# How to avoid having new wireless networks be connected to automatically by default

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager

Under 12.04.3, newly added wireless networks will have their "Connect automatically" box checked by default.  Is there a way to arrange for this box to be unchecked by default, so I don't have to remember to go in and uncheck it every time I connect to a new network?  Is there another way to prevent automatic reconnections to new wireless networks?

I would consider "upgrade to 12.10, 13.04, etc." a valid (though not preferred) answer if that will solve the problem.

Comment: I think the root of the problem is the way the defaults are set by a 'no setting equals True'  schema.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257549/is-there-any-way-to-disable-automatically-connect-to-this-network-when-availabl