# Disable connection's auto-connect by default in network-manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, default

I would like to ask how to disable/enable auto-connect on new connections. There are many questions regarding similar thing, so I post pics to clarify.
I want to turn off ticked box saying Automatically connect to this network when it is available by default for all future connections. So I dont have to do it manually for each new connection.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfIvs.png)

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Related q:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/389449/how-to-avoid-having-new-wireless-networks-be-connected-to-automatically-by-defau?rq=1

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36866/ubuntu-automatically-connects-to-a-wireless-network-when-its-already-connected-b

Comment: I think the root of the problem is the way the defaults are set by a 'no setting equals True'  schema.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257549/is-there-any-way-to-disable-automatically-connect-to-this-network-when-availabl